# The relation between the probability of roulette spins and the normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I understand that a roulette spin (we only consider the outcomes black and red here) will always have a probability of 50%, since it is independent from previous results.

It is also said, that a series of roulette spins follow the multiplication principle. Thus, both RRRRRB and RBRBRB have a probability of 1/2^6=1/64

But now I'm thinking: **Why doesn't the outcome of a series of roulette spins follow the normal distribution, so that RBRBRB has a higher probability of RRRRRB?**

Comment: It follows a *binomial* distribution, which for large $n$ approaches a Gaussian (normal) when you plot the probability of getting $k$ ${\bf B}$s and $(n - k)$ ${\bf R}$s.

Comment: A random variable that is normally distributed has to be continuous. An outcome corresponding to a series of six Roulette spins may be regarded as the random vector $(X_1, \ldots , X_6)$ where the $X_i'$s are iid and $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ which is necessarily discrete. On the other hand, if $X$ counts the number of $R'$s among your six Roulette spins, the $X\sim\text{Binomial}(6,1/2)$

Comment: There are six ways to get five Rs and a B, because there are six places to put the B.  There are twenty ways to get three Rs and three Bs.  But each of them has probability 1/64.